# What is the generating function for $(a_n)_{0\leq n}$, where $a_n$ is defined as $a_0 = 0$ and $a_{n+1} = a_n + (n+1)^3$ for all $n\geq0$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I have an idea of how to approach this problem, but I am rather confused by generating functions so I do not know if some of the steps I take are correct/allowed. I started this by noting that the function we are looking for is $f(x) = \sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^n$.
Since the sequence can be defined recursively by $a_0 = 0$ and $a_{n+1} = a_n + (n+1)^3$ for all $n\geq0$, I multiplied each of the parts by $x^n$ and summed to get
$$\sum_{n\geq0}a_{n+1}x^n = \sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^n + \sum_{n\geq0}(n+1)^3x^n$$
Which I rewrote as
$$\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\geq0}a_{n+1}x^{n+1} = f(x) + \sum_{n\geq0}(n+1)^3x^n$$
And, since $a_0 = 0$, 
$$\frac{1}{x}f(x) = f(x) + \sum_{n\geq0}(n+1)^3x^n$$
I then subtracted $f(x)$ from both sides to obtain
$$\frac{1-x}{x}f(x) = \sum_{n\geq0}(n+1)^3x^n$$
This is where I got stuck. I think the next step would be to say, since $0^3 = 0$, we can rewrite it as
$$\frac{1-x}{x}f(x) = \sum_{n\geq0}n^3x^n$$
I am not sure if this works/is true? In a previous problem, we derived the generating function for $(n^3)$, so I subsituted it in here
$$\frac{1-x}{x}f(x) = \frac{x^3+4x^2+x}{(1-x)^4}$$
And lastly multiplied both sides by $\frac{x}{1-x}$ to obtain
$$f(x) = \frac{x^4+4x^3+x^2}{(1-x)^5}$$
So, does this look right? Is the maths correct? I am still new to generating functions so I am still confused by a lot of the rules and what you can and cannot do.

Comment: Could you make sure the title and the body are in sync please? E.g. $a_0=0$ is only in the title.

Comment: My apologies, first post on here! I think I fixed it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I suppose that in the title it shall be $(a_n)_{0 \le n}$ isn't it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(A lot of people wrote long answers with alternate solutions and ideas -- I am suspicious some may  not have actually read your post. Probably it will be more helpful to you to get direct feedback on what you did, so I will do that.)*

It's almost a fully correct solution.
The only error is when you replaced $\sum_{n \ge 0} (n+1)^3 x^n$ with $\sum_{n \ge 0} n^3 x^n$.

> I am not sure if this works/is true?

It doesn't quite. Let's do it more carefully, by changing the index $n$ to $n' = n+1$ (so conversely, $n = n' - 1$):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \ge 0} (n+1)^3 x^n
  &= \sum_{\color{red}{n' \ge 1}} (\color{red}{n'})^3 x^{\color{red}{n' - 1}} \\
  &= \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n' \ge 1} (n')^3 x^{n'} \\
  &= \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n' \ge 0} (n')^3 x^{n'} \quad (\text{since } 0^3 = 0)\\
  &= \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \ge 0} n^3 x^n \quad \text{(rename the variable)}
\end{align*}

OK, so you'll end up with the same thing as before, but with an additional $\frac{1}{x}$ factor.

Comment: You are wrong ... we read carefully ... thank you for contributing to down-voting!

Comment: @rtybase Your answer was quite reasonable with good advice, and does not imply you didn't read the OP. It didn't get downvoted and (by implication) I didn't downvote it. I downvoted one answer, a ridiculous "hint" which literally provides exactly the method of solution that the OP did.

Comment: It is unfortunate on this site that no one gives direct feedback on what the OP tried, especially when they clearly know what they are doing in almost all steps. Hardly a good way to learn mathematics to have alternate solutions and formulas thrown at you. The practice of doing mathematics is to try things yourself, not read other people's solutions.

Comment: Yep, I think it was OP who removed the vote, that's fine ... my point was that such typical typos are the result of messing with indexes, thus my recommendation to avoid it at any cost

Comment: @rtybase It was not the OP: OP does not have enough reputation to downvote. It would be best not to jump to such conclusions about downvoting. You have been wrong twice now. I agree with the advice about indices.

Comment: OP final $f(x)$ is correct, there's no additional $1/x$.

Comment: @GCab No I don't think so. It's divisible by $x^2$, yet $a_1 = 1$, not $0$. Your solution is pretty complicated so I didn't check it.

Comment: I checked my answer before posting and now added it . Can you check your results ?

Comment: @GCab Your answer is right, but it's not the same as the OP's answer as you said in your answer. OP has an extra factor of $x$.

Comment: You are fully right, really sorry, I wrongly compared OP's  result to mine.

Comment: @6005 thank you for this, quite helpful! I am a bit confused however with the final step... how can you substitute n' with n when n' was defined in terms of n?

Comment: @Mking We defined $n' = n + 1$, and it follows from that $n = n' - 1$. Since both of these equations are true, you can substitute either one. It's like if $2+2=4$, you can substitute $4$ for $2+2$, or you can substitute $2+2$ for $4$, either way.

Comment: However, if it helps you think about it more clearly, you can just do the substitutions in one direction: substitute all the $n$s with $n'-1$, and then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to write down the generating function from the recurrence
is as recommended in the renowned "Concrete Mathematics", that is

a) make clear that (as usually is ) the variable is defined to be null for negative values of the index
$$a_n=0\quad|\; n<0$$.

b) rewrite the recurrence putting the higher index at $n$, and you have better to arrange with RHS $=0$.
$$
a_{\,n}  - a_{\,n - 1}  - n^{\,3}  = 0
$$

c) by resorting to [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
$$
\left[ P \right] = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & {P = TRUE}  \\
   0 & {P = FALSE}  \\
 \end{array} } \right.
$$
introduce suitable terms, such as to make the equation valid for all $0 \le n$.
In your case, for $n=0$, the equation becomes $a_0=0$ and we do not need any additional term.
Otherwise in the LHS we should have added $-a_0\left[ 0=n \right]$: let's do it, so to make the case more general.

d) multiply by $x^n$ and sum for $0 \le n$
$$
\eqalign{
  & 0 = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {a_{\,n} \,x^{\,n} }  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {a_{\,n - 1} \,x^{\,n} }  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n^{\,3} \,x^{\,n} }  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {a_{\,0} \left[ {0 = n} \right]\,x^{\,n} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {a_{\,n} \,x^{\,n} }  - x\,\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {a_{\,n - 1} \,x^{\,n - 1} }  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n^{\,3} \,x^{\,n} }  - a_{\,0}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {a_{\,n} \,x^{\,n} }  - x\,\left( {a_{\, - 1} x^{\, - 1}  + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {a_{\,n} \,x^{\,n} } } \right) - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n^{\,3} \,x^{\,n} }  - a_{\,0}  =   \cr 
  &  = F(x) - x\,F(x) - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n^{\,3} \,x^{\,n} }  - a_{\,0}  =   \cr 
  &  = F(x) - x\,F(x) - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n\,x^{\,n} }  - 3\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n\left( {n - 1} \right)\,x^{\,n} }  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n\left( {n - 1} \right)\left( {n - 2} \right)\,x^{\,n} }  - a_{\,0}  =   \cr 
  &  = F(x) - x\,F(x) - x\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n\,x^{\,n - 1} }  - 3x^{\,2} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n\left( {n - 1} \right)\,x^{\,n - 1} }  - x^{\,3} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n\left( {n - 1} \right)\left( {n - 2} \right)\,x^{\,n - 3} }  - a_{\,0}  \cr} 
$$

e) to conclude that
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {1 - x} \right)F(x) = x\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n\,x^{\,n - 1} }  + 3x^{\,2} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n\left( {n - 1} \right)\,x^{\,n - 1} }  + x^{\,3} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {n\left( {n - 1} \right)\left( {n - 2} \right)\,x^{\,n - 3} }  + a_{\,0}  =   \cr 
  &  = a_{\,0}  + x{d \over {dx}}\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\, - 1}  + 3x^{\,2} {{d^{\,2} } \over {dx^{\,2} }}\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\, - 1}  + x^{\,3} {{d^{\,3} } \over {dx^{\,3} }}\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\, - 1}  =   \cr 
  &  = a_{\,0}  + {x \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,2} }} + {{6x^{\,2} } \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,3} }} + {{6x^{\,3} } \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,4} }} =   \cr 
  &  = {{a_{\,0} \left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,4}  + x\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,2}  + 6x^{\,2} \left( {1 - x} \right) + 6x^{\,3} } \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,4} }} \cr} 
$$
i.e.
$$
\eqalign{
  & F(x) = {{a_{\,0} \left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,4}  + x\left( {1 + 4x + x^{\,2} } \right)} \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,5} }} =   \cr 
  &  = {{a_{\,0} } \over {1 - x}} - {1 \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,2} }} + {7 \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,3} }} - {{12} \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,4} }} + {6 \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,5} }} \cr} 
$$

So, your solution contains an extra $x$ factor . If you want to avoid (as much as possible) uncertainties in developing more complicated ogfs, I do suggest to you to get acquainted with the procedure above.

**check**

For $a_0=0$ the Taylor series of $F(x)$ gives the following coefficients
$$
0,1,9,36,100,225,441,\cdots
$$
which corresponds to
$$
a_{\,n}  - a_{\,n - 1}  = 0,1,8,27,64,125,216, \cdots  = n^{\,3} 
$$

Or more rigorously
$$
\eqalign{
  & F(x) = {{a_{\,0} } \over {1 - x}} - {1 \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,2} }} + {7 \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,3} }} - {{12} \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,4} }} + {6 \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,5} }} =   \cr 
  &  = a_{\,0} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {x^{\,n} }  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  1 + n \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)x^{\,n} }  + 7\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  2 + n \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)x^{\,n} }  - 12\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  3 + n \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)x^{\,n} }  + 6\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  4 + n \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)x^{\,n} }  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow a_{\,n}  = a_{\,0}  - \left( \matrix{
  1 + n \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right) + 7\left( \matrix{
  2 + n \cr 
  2 \cr}  \right) - 12\left( \matrix{
  3 + n \cr 
  3 \cr}  \right) + 6\left( \matrix{
  4 + n \cr 
  4 \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = a_{\,0}  - \left( {n + 1} \right) + 7{{\left( {n + 2} \right)\left( {n + 1} \right)} \over 2} - 2\left( {n + 3} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)\left( {n + 1} \right) + {{\left( {n + 4} \right)\left( {n + 3} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)\left( {n + 1} \right)} \over 4} =   \cr 
  &  = a_{\,0}  + \left( {{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)} \over 2}} \right)^{\,2}  \cr} 
$$
and in conclusion
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
F(x) = {{a_{\,0} \left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,4}  + x\left( {1 + 4x + x^{\,2} } \right)} \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,5} }}\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad a_{\,n}  = a_{\,0}  + \left( {{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)} \over 2}} \right)^{\,2} \quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left\{ {\matrix{
   {a_{\,0}  = a_{\,0} }  \cr 
   {a_{\,n}  - a_{\,n - 1}  = n^{\,3} }  \cr 
   {a_{\,n + 1}  - a_{\,n}  = \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,3} }  \cr 
 } } \right.
 }$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll post an incomplete solution and leave it to you to finish it:

$$\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n>0}a_nx^n}&=x\sum_{n\ge0}a_{n+1}x^n\\
&=x\sum_{n\ge0}(a_n+(n+1)^3)x^n\\
&=x\left(\color{blue}{\sum_{n>0}a_n x^n}+\sum_{n\ge0}(n+1)^3x^n\right)\\
\end{align*}$$

Take particular note of the indexing changes I did, which exploit the initial condition $a_0=0$.

You should be able to evaluate one of the sums explicitly, and then solve for the unknown sum.

Comment: ...Did you bother reading the post and seeing that the OP did exactly this?

Comment: He went about it too complicated-like (e.g. dividing too early by $x$).

Comment: (1) nothing in the post indicates "He". (2) dividing by x instead of multiplying is a mistake now? :-/

Comment: After evaluating the last sum in black by deriving it from the usual geometric series, you can postpone a division to the very end after isolating the sum in blue. Honestly, even your solution having that hanging $\frac1x$ makes it look unwieldy.

Comment: It's obviously the same thing -- I don't know what you find "unwieldy" about division by $x$. No point in arguing about this...

Comment: Your glib dismissal of this being the "same thing" seems to be the same criterion as my finding your solution unappealing. But, I don't really need to be conversing any further with you about this. :P

Answer (score 0):

The definition of generating functions is very clear $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$. I prefer not ignoring $a_0$ to avoid messing with the indexes and, typically, you calculate it from the initial conditions, which you mentioned only in the title. So, I will treat it as unknown parameter for the purpose of the calculations below.

Thus
$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=
a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n=
a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n-1}+n^3)x^n=\\
a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^n+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^3x^n=
a_0+x\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^3x^n=\\
a_0+x\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^3x^n=a_0+xf(x)+x\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^3x^{n-1}=\\
a_0+xf(x)+x\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^{n}\right)'=
a_0+xf(x)+x\left(x\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^{n-1}\right)'=\\
a_0+xf(x)+x\left(x\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n}\right)'\right)'=
a_0+xf(x)+x\left(x\left(x\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^{n}\right)'\right)'=\\
a_0+xf(x)+x\left(x\left(\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \right)'\right)'=
a_0+xf(x)+\frac{x^3+4x^2+x}{(1-x)^4}$$
and 
$$f(x)=\frac{a_0}{1-x}+\frac{x^3+4x^2+x}{(1-x)^5}$$